# mongoose aggregate sort one array by field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregate

I would like to fetch only one element from each group of fields:
here is my result

```
[{
"_id":{"device_id":"9"},
"x":["2019-11-17T18:03:33.000Z","2019-11-17T12:02:35.000Z"],
"y":["93","3"]
},
{
"_id":{"device_id":"8"},
"x":["2019-11-16T12:05:33.000Z","2019-11-16T12:02:35.000Z"],
"y":["33","3"]
}]
```

I would like to get only the last inserted data, means only one value from x and one value from y.
This is the code :

```
aggregate([
            { "$sort": { "timeStamp": -1 } },
            {
                $group:
                {
                    _id: { device_id: '$device_id' },
                    x: {
                        $push: "$timeStamp"

                    },
                    y: {
                        $push: "$value"
                    },
                    device_name: {
                        $push: "$device_name"
                    },
                }
            }
}]
```

I have tried to add project exp:

```
 {
    $project: {
        time: "$x",
        value:"$y",
        integerValues:{
            $map:{
                input: "x",
                as: "integerValue",
                in: { $trunc: "$$integerValue" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the result I expect to have it:

```
{
    "_id":{"device_id":"8"},
    "x":["2019-11-16T12:05:33.000Z"],
    "y":["33"]
},
{
    "_id":{"device_id":"9"},
    "x":["2019-11-17T18:03:33.000Z"],
    "y":["93"]
}
```

I was searching so much about this problem without any solution

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a single project stage

```
aggregate([{
  $project: {
    x: {
      $max: "$x"
    },
    y: {
      $max: "$y"
    }
  }
}])
```

The result you get will be something like this,

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "device_id": "9"
    },
    "x": "2019-11-17T18:03:33.000Z",
    "y": "93"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "device_id": "8"
    },
    "x": "2019-11-16T12:05:33.000Z",
    "y": "33"
  }
]
```